# Looking for only-tty iso image

Tags: startup, iso, tty

I would like to know if there is a mini iso image that contains only the system, not the graphical environment.

It just want the tty, like [ttylinux](http://ttylinux.net/) ( but ubuntu kernel )

I am thinking that i do not need Unity or other environments except the terminal.

( Sometimes more than one Virtual Machines opened, are to heavy for old computers. )

Thank you, GeoMint

Comment: Have you tried Ubuntu's `mini.iso`? This ISO file is very small and you can choose what you want to install during the installation. You could also try Ubuntu Server.

Comment: I saw this in debians website but i thought that it downloads files after install th base system. Hmm i will search for it and try it. thanks

Comment: Yes, `mini.iso` only contains the installer. Everything else will be downloaded during the installation, so you need an internet connection. I think you can install Ubuntu Server without an internet connection.

Comment: I just downloaded [ununtu server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server). i will try this one. Do you know where i can find the mini.iso ?

Comment: You can find it [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/mini.iso). This ISO is for `amd64`. For other architectures just replace `amd64` in the URL.